# Display image with delete button in each

Tags: jquery

I have code that displays the image after selecting a file. However, I don't know how to go about deleting the display image. So, I'd like to have a delete button on each image so it can easily be deleted by the user. What to do?

```
<div id="list" style="width:800px;border:1pt solid black"></div>
  <script>
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        function handleFileSelect(evt) {


        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {


        if(x > 9)
        {
            alert('Total of 10 Images are acceptable');
        }
        else
        {

          // Only process image files.
          if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
          }

          var reader = new FileReader();

          // Closure to capture the file information.
          reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
              // Render thumbnail.
              var span = document.createElement('span');
              span.innerHTML = ['<div id="image"><img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                                '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/></div>'].join('');
              document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);   
            };
          })(f);

          // Read in the image file as a data URL.
          reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
        }
        y = i + x;
        x = 0 + y;
        i = 0;  
    }
      document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: You could add a `<a class="delete-image" data-image-id="e.target.result.id">Delete Image</a>` to `span.innerHTML`, (assuming the image id is stored `e.traget.result.id`) That's an example for a delete button.

Comment: Am I use function to delete it ? @yoshi

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do ajax:

1. add 1onclick="deleteImg('img id or something else')";1
2. create JavaScript function `deleteImg`

   ```
   function deleteImg(par){
      // do ajax POST to delete image from db
   }
   ```
3. On the response you can make `.hide()` of the image